# Difference between ListView and Column?

Tags: flutter

When creating a very simple scrollable list in Flutter, what are the advantages and disadvantages of saying (where `widgets is List<Widget> == true`):

Option 1:

```
var widget = new SingleChildScrollView( 
  child: new Column(
    chidren: widgets
));
```

Option 2:

```
var widget = new ListView(children: widgets);
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**ListView:**

Listview Widget shows the unlimited number of children inside it, but the main advantage of using ListView is it renders only visible items on the screen perhaps more specifically I would say `ListView.Builder()`

**Column**

The column is used when we have to draw different widgets in the list. If items increase in the `column` then `SingleChildScrollView` is used for scrolling purposes.

Answer (score 17):

Definitely go for option 2.
`ListView` have a few cool optimisations. https://youtu.be/UUfXWzp0-DU?t=33m38s